# Specified cast is not valid C# Console App

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

This is the error im getting..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeOaD.png

Here is my code..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace LoginServer
{
[Serializable]
class MessageData
{
    public int type = 0;
    public string stringData = "";

    public static MessageData FromByteArray(byte[] input)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(input);
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        MessageData data = new MessageData();
        data.type = (int)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        data.stringData = (string)formatter.Deserialize(stream);

        if (data.stringData == "")
        {
            data.type = 999;
            data.stringData = "No command included";
        }

        return data;
    }

    public static byte[] ToByteArray(MessageData msg)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        formatter.Serialize(stream, msg.type);
        formatter.Serialize(stream, msg.stringData);

        return stream.ToArray();
      }
   }
}
```

Really not sure why I cant use this cast as an int..

I've spent a lot of time trying to fix this, even using an const int but that doesn't fix the problem.

set type as an int and data is MessageData, so the int should work fine....

Please help.

Comment: Please put the error as *text* in your question and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

You should replace both the cast you do:

```
data.type = (int)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
data.stringData = (string)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
```

with the following one:

```
data = (MessageData)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
```

since the object you should deserialize it should be of type `MessageData`. Furthermore, you have to change also the following:

```
formatter.Serialize(stream, msg.type);
formatter.Serialize(stream, msg.stringData);
```

with this:

```
formatter.Serialize(stream, msg);
```

Usually we serialize an object and then we deserialize the result in order to get the original object. We don't serialize each property of the objet separately and then deserialize them one after the other separately.

For a basic serialization approach, pleaes have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/serialization/basic-serialization).

Comment: Tried that but it didnt work System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'LoginServer.MessageData'.'

Comment: I think that we miss something here. Do you have this `var stream = new MemoryStream(input);
var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        var data = (MessageData)formatter.Deserialize(stream);` in from `FromByteArray` method and it doesn't work? I suppose that you have also changed the corresponding code mentioned above in the `ToByteArray` method.

Comment: My MessageData script is used with LoginServer script  here is my login server  https://pastebin.com/4dxh29jE

Comment: @BarryHanbury please have a look at this https://dotnetfiddle.net/cdqsLC fiddle, where I have made the changes mentioned above and it seems that it works. Thanks